# FileNotFoundException when accessing an image with Korge

Tags: file, kotlin, korge

I have an Android application and I used Korge dependencies to make my game. I'm trying to load an image and I got a **FileNotFoundException** exception, wherever I put the file. Here's my code :

```
val topArrowImg = resourcesVfs["top_arrow.png"].readBitmap()
```

And my project structure :

[image: Project structure]

Does anyone know where I have to put this file ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

`resourcesVfs` points to files in `src/main/res`, e.g. `resourcesVfs["top_arrow.png"]` points to the file at `src/main/res/top_arrow.png`